# Mathematica PDF Error

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to create a pdf document of my mathematica codes, when I press save as>PDF, it creates only one page. But I have fifteen pages totally. Is there any solution for the true printing?

Comment: works for me. What OS, mathematica version, etc?

Comment: Windows 7, Wolfram Mathematica 9.0

Comment: agentp do you have any idea? Is there any setting for printing?